# Repeat insert SQL query with one column value change

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table name 'emp_records' which has entries like:

```
Point_name |     date      | value  |
X          | 2016-02-01    | 22.2   |
Y          | 2016-02-01    | 44     |
Z          | 2016-02-01    | 10.4   |
X          | 2016-02-02    | 2.8    |
Y          | 2016-02-02    | 22.5   |
Z          | 2016-02-02    | 15.4   |
.
.
.
```

So, there are entries for X,Y,Z corresponding to every date.
Now I want to do the following thing:
Assuming today's date is: 2016-03-15

1. Get the entries for X,Y,Z having latest date in the table, say the latest entries for X,Y,Z are upto date 2016-02-20
2. Copy the these entries from 2016-02-20 to (current date - 1) i.e, 2016-03-14. Only the date column should change for each set of X,Y,Z.
   For example, if the latest entry set is for 2016-02-20:

```
Point_name |     date      | value  |
X          | 2016-02-20    | 20.5   |
Y          | 2016-02-20    | 39     |
Z          | 2016-02-20    | 11.4   |
```

Duplicate this set upto current date - 1
like:

```
Point_name |     date      | value  |
X          | 2016-02-21    | 20.5   |
Y          | 2016-02-21    | 39     |
Z          | 2016-02-21    | 11.4   |
X          | 2016-02-22    | 20.5   |
Y          | 2016-02-22    | 39     |
Z          | 2016-02-22    | 11.4   |
X          | 2016-02-23    | 20.5   |
Y          | 2016-02-23    | 39     |
Z          | 2016-02-23    | 11.4   |
X          | 2016-02-24    | 20.5   |
Y          | 2016-02-24    | 39     |
Z          | 2016-02-24    | 11.4   |
X          | 2016-02-25    | 20.5   |
Y          | 2016-02-25    | 39     |
Z          | 2016-02-25    | 11.4   |
.                 .            .
.                 .            .
.                 .            .
X          | 2016-03-14    | 20.5   |
Y          | 2016-03-14    | 39     |
Z          | 2016-03-14    | 11.4   |
```

This is just a sample table by which I am asking my doubt. The actual table contains 9 different Point names and many other columns as well. Can  anyone help to write this in a single SQL query ?

Comment: Which language are you using with MySQL ??? [because in my view this is not possible with one Query] (Though! if you want to do it in 2-steps, I can help you....)

Comment: @user3078630, did any of the answers suit your needs? Could you provide some feed-back?

Answer (score 0):

This statement does what you want

```
insert into @emp_records SELECT point_name,dateadd(d,-1,GETDATE()),value
           FROM @emp_records WHERE DATE IN (SELECT MAX(DATE) FROM @emp_records)
```

I used this statement below to test it.

```
DECLARE @emp_records TABLE (point_name VARCHAR(5),[DATE] DATE,VALUE DECIMAL(18,2))
INSERT INTO @emp_records VALUES ('X','02/20/2016',20.3)
INSERT INTO @emp_records VALUES ('Y','02/20/2016',10.7)
INSERT INTO @emp_records VALUES ('Z','02/20/2016',12.8)
insert into @emp_records SELECT point_name,dateadd(d,-1,GETDATE()),value
       FROM @emp_records WHERE DATE IN (SELECT MAX(DATE) FROM @emp_records)
SELECT * FROM @emp_records
```

Comment: Hey Shukri, I didn't understang this part: dateadd(d,-1,GETDATE())

Answer (score 0):

In MySql there is no way to produce a dynamic number of rows if you don't have a table (or inline query) producing these rows. As your most recent date could potentially be in the remote past, you might need a lot of these records.

So I would suggest to first create a helper table called *series*. This you need to do one time only:

```
create table series (
  n int auto_increment,
  primary key (n)
);

insert into series values (); -- 1 record
insert into series select null from series; -- 2 records
insert into series select null from series; -- 4 records
insert into series select null from series; -- 8 records
insert into series select null from series; -- 16 records
insert into series select null from series; -- 32 records
insert into series select null from series; -- 64 records
insert into series select null from series; -- 128 records
insert into series select null from series; -- 256 records
insert into series select null from series; -- 1024 records
insert into series select null from series; -- 2048 records
```

You can repeat that `insert` to double the number of records in that table until you have enough. But 2000 already covers 6 years of days, so practically this could be more than enough.

Then your insert statement becomes:

```
insert into emp_records (point_name, date, value)
    select point_name,
           DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL  series.n DAY) as date,
           value
    from   emp_records,
           series
    where  date = (select max(date) from emp_records)
    and    DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL  series.n DAY) <= CURDATE();
```

[This](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0dbecd/5) is a fiddle that shows the result of the `select` part.

Answer (score 0):

First fetch the `emp_records` having the `MAX` Date for each `Point_name`. (The below query give you the records of `MAX(DATE)` for each point you have in the `table`):

```
SELECT * FROM 
( 
    SELECT 
        Point_name, date, value 
    FROM 
        emp_records 
    ORDER BY 
      Point_name , date DESC 
)   myAlias 
GROUP BY 
    Point_name
```

---

Now that, when you have got the `emp_records` which need to be inserted (build your query string, by iterating the above result):

```
/* PSUEDO-CODE (As Server-side Language not tagged) */
/* DECLARE a variable holding the Query-String */
string queryString = "INSERT INTO emp_records (Point_name, date, value) VALUES "; 
/* GET the Current-Date in the language, you are using */
string dateString = "2016-03-15"; 
/* ITERATE the Fetched-Data resulted from the First-Query to Build the INSERT Query */
for(i=0; i<FetchedArray.Length; i++) 
{ 
    /* GET the Days-Difference in dateString and FetchedArray['date'] */
    for(j=1; j <= numberOfDifferenceDays; j++) 
    { 
        /* DECLARE a Variable having the Date tobe inserted named as insertDate */
        insertDate = FetchedArray['date'].AddDays(j); 
        /* CONCATENATE the queryString */
        queryString += "(" +    FetchedArray['Point_name'] + 
                         ", " + insertDate + ", " + 
                         ", " + FetchedArray['value'] + "), ";
    } 
} 
/* 
 AT the end of this Iteration, 
 you would get a INSERT-QUERY that needs to be executed 
 to get what you wanted
 Display variable queryString to check if requirement has fulfilled
 Remove the COMMA at the end of the variable queryString 
 If you have the Correct Insert-Query (Execute it)
*/
```